# Bootstrap input field width too small

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying change the width of the input field for the username and password. But nothing seems to happen

```
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Login </a>
                    <form class="dropdown-menu p-4 dropdown-menu-right" method="post" action="#">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
                                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
                                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </li>
```

[image]

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_forms_sizing.asp

Comment: I've already tried, it does not change the width of the input field.

Comment: Include *all* of the relevant code. What is the dropdown contained in?

Comment: It's contained in a `<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">`

Comment: when i remove `class="form-control"` then it stops become bootstrap input field and then the size seems reasonable.